# autocomplete using jQuery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I would like to know how I can use autocomplete feature in jQuery.

I already have an arraylist of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery autocomplete plugin is [available here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) with source and example.